# Accidently Deleted Contents of Azure Mobile Service table

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I was deleting a single record in the Classic Azure Portal in Mobile Services Browse. The entire contents of the table has now disappeared. Please help!!! How do I restore the contents. The table and scripts are still there.

I have gone into the SQL database tab and clicked restore from point in time, this creates a new DB  but does not give me an option to restore to Azure mobile services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restoring a database always creates a new database on the same server as the original database, so the restored database must be given a new name. Once complete, the restored database is a normal fully accessible online database charged at normal rates based on its service tier and performance level. If you are restoring the database for recovery purposes you can treat the restored database as a replacement for the original database, or use it to retrieve data from and then update the original database. Please check [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-database-point-in-time-restore/) for details.

So if you are going to use the new database, you can re-configure your mobile service to use the new database as following snapshot shows(click the mobile service, go to **configure** tab then click **change database**):
[image]
[image]